# MySQL copy two table columns to another table with different column names

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**pages1**

```
+---------------+-------------+
| id            | int         |
+---------------+-------------+
| content       | medium_text |
+---------------+-------------+
| date_modified | int         |
+---------------+-------------+
```

**pages2**

```
+---------+-------------+
| id      | int         |
+---------+-------------+
| content | medium_text |
+---------+-------------+
| date    | int         |
+---------+-------------+
```

I'm having trouble copying `content` and `date_modified` columns from the `pages1` table to the `content` and `date` columns in the `pages2` table.

I get `Unknown column` errors and I've attempted to use `AS` (alias) in case it was a mismatch though I'm 100% certain the columns exist. I've used the obnoxious ticks and the whole nine yards:

```
INSERT INTO pages2 (`content`, `date`) VALUES
(SELECT `content`, `date_modified` FROM `pages` WHERE `pages2`.`id` = `pages`.`id`);
```

Comment: remove `values` from your insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
INSERT INTO pages2 (`content`, `date`) 
SELECT `content`, `date_modified` FROM `pages` WHERE `pages2`.`id` = `pages`.`id`;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO pages2 (`content`, `date`) 
SELECT `content`, `date_modified` FROM `pages`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO pages2 (`content`, `date`) 
SELECT `content`, `date_modified` 
FROM `pages`
inner join pages2 on `pages`.`id` = `pages2`.`id`;
```